# How to catch Amazon AWS errors Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-simpledb

I am constantly getting  error reports (from users) such as:

Caused by: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonSimpleDB, AWS Request ID: c5cb109d-bbff-fcea-bc0d-0cb60ff8f6af, AWS Error Code: RequestExpired, AWS Error Message: Request has expired. Timestamp date is 2012-06-06T13:19:59.415Z. Current date is 2012-06-06T14:20:03Z

Apparently this is because the user has the wrong timezone or something set? Regardless, I would like to catch this particular error and post a message to the user asking them to check their timezone settings however I can't find a way to do it. If I catch AmazonServiceException, the error shows up as null.

How can I catch errors based on Status Code or even Error Code?  The current code that I tried looks like this:

```
try {
        dostuff()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        updateAWS("DownloadErrors");
        return "filenotfound";
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        return "downloadfail";
    }
```

However AmazonServiceException e is always null so I can't pull any information from it.

other code:

```
private void doStuff() throws IOException, AmazonServiceException{ 
//code here
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the "simpledb" tag. Also- a regular "Exception" doesn't get this? `e.getMessage()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you explain?

Comment: You're using specific Exceptions, but not a catchall kind of Exception, add `} catch (Exception e){  Log.e("myapp",e.getMessage()); }` to the end of your catch.

Comment: Tried that.  Exception e still is caught but e is null, just like the situation above.  Plus catching Exception e is considered bad coding.

Comment: So the status code message you're seeing is in LogCat?

Comment: FYI, looks like AWS is battling with this with other devs, and they're releasing a new SDK: <https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=348058&#348058>

Comment: Check your emulator's time is the learning I got from AWS forums. If you're basing this issue on your emulator (vs. live user reports).

Comment: Yes, the status code is in logcat (for errors other than the timestamp).  The time stamp error is in live user reports.  Also, I did download the new SDK but haven't deployed it.  Looking throught the changelog I don't anticipate a fix from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is what I needed.  SDb tracks "RequestExpired" and S3 uses "RequestTimeTooSkewed"

Also, this appears to be occurring because the system time is >15 minutes different than the AWS server.  I put a note to the user to check their time and use "Automatic" date/time if possible.  Tested it myself and reproduced the error as well as the solution.

```
try {
        result = doOperations();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        if (e.getErrorCode().equals("RequestExpired") || e.getErrorCode().equals("RequestTimeTooSkewed")) {
            result = "timestamp";
        }
        }
    return result;
}
```